# allocating memory to struct pointer inside array of structure

Tags: c

How can I allocate memory to the struct ptr employee *det; (for size 5) inside the array of struct details?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COMPANY    2
#define MAX        5

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *addr;
    int age;
}employee;

struct {
     employee *det;
} details[COMPANY];

int main()
{
    int i;


    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
        details[i].det = malloc(MAX*sizeof(employee *));


return 0;
}
```

I tried the following but it failed with error:expected expression before 'details'

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    details[i].det = malloc(MAX*sizeof(employee *));
```

Comment: Does `employee det[5]` work?

Comment: it does... but if i want to access it from struct details.. how do i access it? For example :  for (i=0; i<2; i++)
        details[i].det[0].age = 5;   this is throwing an error "expected expression before 'details'"

Comment: `details[i].det[0].age = 5;`

Comment: Also, how can i use malloc for allocating memory in this case? The syntax that i am trying to use is not working and giving me an error.

Comment: Yes, I added it to the main post.

Comment: A struct with a single pointer  in it is a bit strange BTW. Are you planning to add other fields than `det` ?

Comment: yes. actually this is just an example. there are other fields in the array of struct other than det.

Comment: The code in the question compiles fine (and if you add `#include <stdlib.h>` it compiles even without warnings). So where is the problem?

Comment: It is compiling now because of the below suggestion made by Anders, but i wanted to know if this is the right way to malloc the structure.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
details[i]->det = malloc(sizeof(employee));
details[i]->det->name = strdup("name");
details[i]->det->addr = strdup("address");
details[i]->det->arge = 18;
```

strdup is short for malloc and strcpy

**EDIT:**

I am not quite sure why you have the additional layer of "details" in between, you could just write

```
employee* employees = malloc(sizeof(employee)*5);
...
employees[i]->name = strdup("name");
employees[i]->addr = strdup("address");
employees[i]->arge = 18;
```

Comment: Lets say each company has 5 employees.. so totally 10 employees. So, how do i allocate memory per company?

Comment: with a loop and the above code although you may want to add different name and addresses e.g. you can have in a file 10 lines with data that you read in.

Comment: I added to the main post, what i was doing and it is giving me an error. can you tell me what's wrong with that syntax. that will be of great help!

Comment: what is the error? btw instead write `typedef struct {
    employee *det;
} detail; detail details[COMPANY];`

Comment: expected expression before 'details'

Comment: either remove typedef for details or do as i wrote above

Comment: Thanks. after removing typedef i don't see any error in the program. But is the memory allocation correct? i have updated my post with the actual program.

Comment: yes, but you have not allocated for name and address, you need to do that once you want to set them to point to strings.